# Using only free CPU time with Objective-C program

Tags: objective-c

The BOINC client (does distributed processing jobs like SETI@home does) is able to turn processing on or off based on whether *other* processes are using a certain percentage of CPU time. That is, if the user starts to do some work and their processes start using 60% CPU, BOINC can pause to avoid interfering with the user's work.

I would like to do the same thing (monitor CPU usage by other processes). The difficulty as I see it is not monitoring CPU usage, but rather making sure that the information isn't skewed by my own usage. For example, if my process is using a ton of CPU time it may prevent another process from using enough to trigger the pause.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Even a suggestion for what to search for would be useful. I'm not really sure what this feature would be called.

Comment: Simply changing the process' priority from Normal to Lower does wonders.

Comment: 0xHenry, change your comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTask to set the 'nice' value of the process when your process starts.

Also `[[NSThread mainThread] setThreadPriority:0.0]`

where priority value is between 0.0 and 1.0 is a Cocoa API which may save you frakking about with sudo